# How to generate .ko file in linux kernel sources?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am learning linux kernel with the help of qemu. I download the source files of linux kernel(linux-4.4.251) from http://kernel.org, build an initrd and use qemu to boot a system on them.

Recently I am trying to work on the `NAND Flash Simulator` provided by the kernel. It is a kernel module that simulate a virtual Flash device (using RAM by default). I can enable this function with `make menuconfig`, and then recompile the kernel image. In this way, the module will be included statically as a part of the kernel image.

But now I want to generate the corresponding `.ko` file so that I can use `insmod` or `insprobe` to load this module dynamically, and provide some arguments to it to control its behavior (like using a file in stead of RAM to simulate the Flash device).

However, the `make modules` command doesn't generate the `.ko` file for me, even though I have already enabled that module with `make menuconfig`.

```
root@Acesrc:~/linux-4.4.251# ls
arch   build.virt64le  COPYING  crypto         drivers   fs       init  Kbuild   kernel  MAINTAINERS  mm   README          samples  security  tools  virt
block  certs           CREDITS  Documentation  firmware  include  ipc   Kconfig  lib     Makefile     net  REPORTING-BUGS  scripts  sound     usr
root@Acesrc:~/linux-4.4.251# make O=build.virt64le ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- -j2 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/linux-4.4.251/build.virt64le'
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  GEN     ./Makefile
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  Using .. as source for kernel
  CHK     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    ../scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 5 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/linux-4.4.251/build.virt64le'
root@Acesrc:~/linux-4.4.251# find . -name '*.ko'
./build.virt64le/crypto/hmac.ko
./build.virt64le/crypto/sha256_generic.ko
./build.virt64le/crypto/drbg.ko
./build.virt64le/crypto/echainiv.ko
./build.virt64le/crypto/jitterentropy_rng.ko
```

How could I generate the `.ko` file of that modules?

Btw, after I obtained a `.ko` file, where should I put that file so that qemu will load it into the system?

Comment: "In this way, the module will be included statically as a part of the kernel image." - It seems you have set `CONFIG_MTD_NAND_NANDSIM` option to `y`. You need to set this option to `m` for geneate a module (`nandsim.ko`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks， it works.  After I get the "nandsim.ko", I copy it to the initrd(built with a busybox). And then I boot the system with qemu, and run `insmod nandsim.ko` to load this module. I can see a new mtd by reading `/proc/mtd`: 
mtd1: 08000000 00004000 "NAND simulator partition 0".  However, the `/dev/mtd1` doesn't exist so I can't mount the Flash. Is there anyway to fix it?